# For temperature time series (MYD11A2) in a year, how to determine the date when the temperature is greater than a threshold for the first time?

Tags: google-earth-engine

The goal is to determine the start of growing season for rice in cold region annually (taking 2019 as an example) using the MODIS Terra temperature dataset, which is defined as the night temperature greater than 278.15 kelvin degree (5 celsius degree) for the first time. Thanks in advance for any hints.

```
// MODIS LST product
var LST = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD11A2")
  .select("LST_Night_1km") // Night temperature in kelvin
  .filterDate("2019", "2020");
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is :

1. turn image date to ee.Image masked with temperature mask.
2. get the minimum value in the stack of images of date.

```
var date2img = function(img){
  img = ee.Image(img);
  var date = img.date().getRelative('day', 'year'); // date in Day-of-Year format
  var scaleFactor = 0.02          // the scale factor for the temperature band is 0.02
  var mask = img.gt(278.15/scaleFactor )   // high temperature mask
  return ee.Image(date).toFloat().updateMask(mask);  
};

var start = LST.map(date2img).min();  // determine the first day of growing season
```